# Arguments of ROS functions

Tags: c++, function, arguments, ros

i have 2 question about ROS function arguments:
look at `addDefaultState` function:

```
addDefaultState (const std::string &name, const std::map< std::string, double > &default_state)
```

first question: what is the meaning of `const`?

second question: what is the meaning of terms inside the `<>` in this case `< std::string, double >`?

thank you

Comment: `const std::string &name` in arguments means that the function `addDefaultState` cannot change the string `name` inside it's body, and same kind of reasoning for `default_state`.
For your second question regarding <>, this `< std::string, double >` specifies the type of key in map to be `std::string` and the type of value in map to be `double`

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. what is the meaning of * inside <>. according to your answer LinkModel is an input which does not change. but what is the meaning of *?
bool moveit::core::JointModelGroup::getEndEffectorTips ( std::vector< const LinkModel * > &  tips ) const

Comment: IMHO, I think you should first go through c++ basics. And regarding your question about '*' in `std::vector< const LinkModel * > & tips`, this function `getEndEffectorTips` takes a list of LinkModel pointers where each is pointing to a constant LinkModel object

Answer (score 2):

Nothing special about ROS here, `const` is easy enough to lookup on its own, but basically means the value can not be changed.

The typename followed by other types within a `<`, `>` are *template* parameters, in this case indicating that it is a map of string keys to double values. Looking for information on C++ templates will provide a great deal of information.